# inputAccessoryView Not calling when keyboard appearing

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate, inputaccessoryview

I have added `InputAccessoryView`to my keyboard disappear. It woks fine. But in some `ViewController` its not appearing. Even that method doesnt call.

I have a button. When I click on that my text field become first responder automatically. (cursor focus on the textField when click on that button) Key board is coming but the input accessory view not coming.

I am testing this on iOS 8.2 device. 
 this is my code

in `viewDidload`

```
 // for search------------------
UIView *srchPadView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 30)];
[srchtextbox setLeftView:srchPadView];
[srchtextbox setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
srchtextbox.attributedPlaceholder=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:alertStrings.strSearch attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.6]}];
[srchtextbox setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
srchtextbox.delegate=self;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:)
 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
 object:srchtextbox];
```

in textfield changing method

```
-(void)textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:(NSNotification *)notification
 {

    isSearching=YES;
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(getSongs)
                                           object:nil];

    loading=YES;
    [mainactivityindicator startAnimating];
    songsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    songstable.hidden=YES;
    startRec=0;

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(getSongs) withObject:nil];


}
```

Then

```
- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView {
if (!inputAccessoryView) {
    CGRect accessFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 40);
    inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:accessFrame];
    inputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:70.0/255 green:70.0/255.0 blue:70.0/255.0 alpha:0.9];

    UIView *line=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
    [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:134.0/255.0 green:139.0/255.0 blue:143.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [inputAccessoryView addSubview:line];

    UIButton *compButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    compButton.frame = CGRectMake(260.0, 2, 60, 37.0);
    [compButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [compButton setTitle: @"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [compButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [compButton addTarget:self action:@selector(completeCurrentWord:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [inputAccessoryView addSubview:compButton];



}
    return inputAccessoryView;
}
```

Finally

```
-(IBAction)completeCurrentWord:(id)sender{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

}

But my `inputAccessoryView` never call. Why is that. How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: where you call your function `- (UIView *)inputAccessoryView`?

Answer (score 6):

You need

1. override method `inputAccessoryView` and return your view.
2. override method:

```
    -(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
        return YES;
    }
```

3.call `[self becomeFirstResponder];` when you need your input accessory view to be visible

Hint:
if you want to be shown always

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Additionally, call `[self resignFirstResponder];` in `viewWillDisappear:` in order to dismiss it animatedly :)